# An inference in counting branch lengths in a Gödel numbering system

Tags: logic, incompleteness

**Set up**

I'm reading a text where formulae are numbered in the following way.  First there is a numbering function $\nu$ such that all logical particles (truth-functional operators and quantifiers, are congruent to some fixed $i$ mod 5).  In the author's choice, $\nu(\neg)=0, \nu(\rightarrow)=5$ and so on with some arbitrary choices all divisible by 5.  For variable $v_n$ we map $\nu(v_n)=5n+1$.  After that we assign $\underline{0}$, the numeral meant to represent the number 0, and $\approx$, the symbol meant to represent equality of terms.  Then the arithmetic operations.

$$\nu(\underline{0})=2,\qquad \nu(\approx)=3\\ \nu({\bf s})=4,\ \nu(+)=9,\ \nu(\cdot)=14$$

The Gödel number of a term or formula is then regarded as a list.  The following defines the Gödel number for terms, in order of variables, the unique constant $\underline{0}$, successor, plus, and times.

$$GN(v_n) = \langle \nu(v_n)\rangle,\ GN(\underline{0})=\langle\nu(\underline{0})\rangle,\ GN({\bf s}(t)) = \langle \nu({\bf s}),GN(t)\rangle \\
GN(t_1+t_2)=\langle \nu(+),GN(t_1),GN(t_2)\rangle\\ GN(t_1\cdot t_2)=\langle \nu(\cdot),GN(t_1),GN(t_2)\rangle$$

Hence every term is coded in a tree structure of nested lists.  We typically use $x$ for the code number of any list of numbers and $y$ for an index in the list, and $(x)_y$ for the number encoded in the $y$th place.  We use formulae to represent numbers and numbers to encode lists.  We have a defined length function,$\ell(x)$, and $th(y,x)$ function so that $\ell(x)$ is the length of list $x$ and $th(y,x)$ is the $y$th coordinate of $x$ and each of these are represented by some formula.  $(x)_y$ is just convenient notation for $th(y,x)$.

**Question**

The author says that, in any given term tree, encoded by $x$ which is a nested list of lists, and for any coordinate $y$, we have $(x)_y<x$ and therefore as we go down a branch the Gödel number of any term decreases.  Ok, that I get by nature of how we've defined the construction of lists.

Next let $t$ be the Gödel number of some term.  The author says that, since at every leaf of the tree we have atomic terms with Gödel number > 0, then every branch must have length $< t$.  This is the part I don't quite get.  I could imagine justifying the conclusion some other way, but I don't see how the given justification is adequate (or even really relevant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine that you had a branch of length $k \ge t$. This means that
$$ ((\cdots((t)_{y_1})_{y_2}\cdots)_{y_{k-1}})_{y_k} $$
for some $y_i$s, is the encoding of a leaf symbol.

But then we have
$$ (t)_{y_1} < t \\
((t)_{y_1})_{y_2} < (t)_{y_1} \\
(((t)_{y_1})_{y_2})_{y_3} < ((t)_{y_1})_{y_2} \\
\vdots $$ 
which, puts together, gives us
$$ (t)_{y_1} \le t-1 \\
((t)_{y_1})_{y_2} \le t-2 \\
(((t)_{y_1})_{y_2})_{y_3} \le t-3 \\
\vdots \\
((\cdots((t)_{y_1})_{y_2}\cdots)_{y_{k-1}})_{y_k} \le t-k \le 0 $$
But no leaf (except $\neg$ which is not allowed in *term* trees anyway) is represented by a number $\le 0$, so this is a contradiction.